# Can I validate "combinations" with XSD's?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

In the following scenario:

```
<apples>
  <isred>1</isred>
  <color>red</color>
</apples>
```

is there a way to create a restriction on the validation of the `isred` element such that when `isred = 1` that `color` must be `red` ?

EDIT: XSD is the only option here.  RelaxNG and Schematron are not available options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To @forty-two 's point, this is an example of an XSD 1.1 that would satisfy your requirement; there's nothing you can do with XSD 1.0 out of the box to address your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org">
    <xsd:element name="apples">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="isred" type="xsd:unsignedByte"/>
                <xsd:element name="color" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:assert test="(isred eq 1 and color eq 'red')" xerces:message="If isred, then color must be red..."/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

An invalid example would show up as:

`cvc-assertion.failure: Assertion failed for schema type '#anonymous'. If isred, then color must be red...`

Answer (score 1):

Probably, with XML schema 1.1 [assertions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/). Haven't used it, and the spec is too convoluted to make a quick decision.